# get object of a list via get in R

Tags: r

I have list which has some objects and I want to get the object in a loop. I use now this code but I don't know why it didn't answer!!

```
test1 <- list(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=rnorm(100))
test1$a
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

but when I want to load it via get in a loop I could't. 
for example

```
get("test1$a")
Error in get("test1$a") : object 'test1$a' not found
```

So, How can I load this objects of a list via a command like this?

Comment: If you'll be looping through the list, `lapply` may be what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
get("test1")$a
```

since the object's name is `test1`, not `test1$a`.